# Minify directories containing CSS and JS recursively with Yui Compressor

Tags: javascript, css, yui-compressor, subdirectory

I have *JS* and *CSS* files scattered around many directories and sub-directories. I just want to specify the top project folder, inside which all these lay, then the entire folders tree should be rebuilt and the minified files placed in their corresponding folder.

For example:

- *my_project/assets/js/test.js*
- *my_project/css/style.css*
- *my_project/jquery.js*

should be minified and placed like this:

- *minified/assets/js/test.js*
- *minified/css/style.css*
- *minified/jquery.js*

Is it possible with **Yui Compressor** to do that? I don't see such options. Is it possible to do it with batch? I know how to get the files but not how to rebuilt the right destionation.

Comment: Do you have gulp in your workflow ? There's a `gulp-yuicompressor` for your usecase